# Mac OS X: Libraries for displaying human anatomy and interacting with it?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I have been asked to implement a way to display an image of a part of human anatomy, such as the spine, and permit the user to interact with it using OS X and Objective C/Swift.  For example, with the spine, I should be able to pull on a vertebra horizontally, thus changing the angle of the spine in that location, or possibly rotating a vertebra clockwise/counterclockwise a few degrees.  I have absolutely no idea how to implement this kind of code.  It seems like animation stuff, but not a video game.  I have seen discussions of Cocoa2D for gaming, but don't know if it is the right path.  Are there any libraries out there that could be used: commercial or otherwise?  I would really appreciate a nudge in the correct direction.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: This is the kind of project that a whole team of people work on, I would imagine.  Even if there was a library that did exactly what you wanted from a code perspective, coming up with the art assets would in of itself be a difficult task.  There are whole products that only do what you're describing.

Comment: I found the following API, https://www.biodigital.com, that is amazing, but I am sure that the price is huge.  Brand new...  My initial though, for 2D rendering, would be to attack the spine in an OOP manner.  Define a class for the vertebra of the spine.  Associate an image with it...  Permit it to do horizontal and some clockwise, CCW rotation.  A spine would be a collection of three types of vertebra (cervical, thoracic, lumbar).  Each vertebra would be separated by an intervertebral disk.  Etc...  Yikes..

Comment: Look at the IGSTK. It's an open source image guided surgery toolbox. There is also at least one open source image database of complete human anatomy.